# Taking multiple inputs and storing them

Tags: java, arrays, input

```
package assign;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class File {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many chef do we have?");
    int x = s.nextInt();
    String [] names = new String[x];
    if(x <= 0) { 
        do { 
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number:");
        x = s.nextInt();
        }while (x <= 0); 
        }

    for (int m = 0; m <= x-1; m++) { 
        System.out.println("Enter the name of " + m + ":");
        String f = s.nextLine();
        names [m] = f;
    }
  }
}
```

So, my purpose is to take names from user as much as s/he wants. But my output from this code is like this:

```
  How many chef do we have?
  3
  Enter the name of 0:
  Enter the name of 1:
  John
  Enter the name of 2:
  Jack
```

When I change the `String f = s.nextLine();` line to `int f = s.nextInt();` the questions come in orders and I am able to write numbers. What should I do to make it like this:

```
   How many chef do we have?
   3
   Enter the name of 0:
   Bob
   Enter the name of 1:
   John
   Enter the name of 2:
   Jack
```

Answer (score 0):

Use`String f = s.next();` instead of `String f = s.nextLine();`